# Inflation index and longevity of modern household appliances

Tags: inflation

The cost of household appliances and TVs are part of the Inflation Index.
It is well known fact that modern appliances and TVs last 1/3 -1/2 time as comparing to 10-20 years ago and every time we buy new item the government collects the taxes. 
Should we prorate the price of the item to it's durability and longevity?
 For example, if the stove price has not changed and is about \$1000, but it lasts only 1/3 of the time it used to work in the past, then its real price for the purpose of calculating the inflation index must be \$3000. Would you agree?

Comment: Government is not responsible for quality control of household appliances. Taxes are what they are. Markets must regulate companies.

Comment: There is some information on how the UK inflation indices take account of changes in the quality of goods [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/inflationandpriceindices/methodologies/consumerpriceinflationincludesall3indicescpihcpiandrpiqmi#validation-and-quality-assurance). It's quite a long way down below the heading "Changes in the quality of products being priced".

Comment: The causality also goes in the other way: one reason for why household appliances and TV have a short living is because they are too cheap. Many are thrown away while they are still functioning.